# Ionic2/Angular2 Event data

Tags: events, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 to create an app.  I have an event:

`import {Events} from 'ionic-angular';`

**publish**

```
let data = {
  topic: 'foo'
};
this.events.publish('messages:notify', data);
```

**subscribe**

```
      this.events.subscribe('messages:notify', (data) => {
        alert(data.topic);
      });
```

I expect it to alert `'foo'`, but it alerts `'undefined'`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `data` is passed as an array, so the following works:

```
  this.events.subscribe('messages:notify', (data) => {
    alert(data[0].topic);
  });
```